# XSLT split at child node

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML code

```
<para>Lorem ipsum <link>dolor</link> sit amet</para>
```

which I want to transform to

```
<para>Lorem ipsum </para><link>dolor</link><para> sit amet</para>
```

In other words: I'd like to split the para element at the position where link element is. Are there any hints?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and very short/simple solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="para/text()">
  <para><xsl:copy-of select="."/></para>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<para>Lorem ipsum <link>dolor</link> sit amet</para>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<para>Lorem ipsum </para><link>dolor</link><para> sit amet</para>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The use of the identity rule** to copy every node as-is.
2. **The overriding of the identity rule** with templates for processing only specific nodes
3. **The utmost simplicity and power** that follow from using 1. and 2. above.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, thank you for your very elegant solution, but I have the problem that the content model of <para> allows some other elements too, which shouldn't end the paragraph like link should. So I had to use Alejandros suggestion.

Comment: @Roman: You can edit your question and show the real structure of your XML, then sure I'll modify my answer to match the XML structure I haven't yet seen. Nobody here is a clairevoyant. :)

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="para">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="link" mode="copy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="para/link"/>
    <xsl:template match="para/link" mode="copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <para>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<para>Lorem ipsum </para><link>dolor</link><para> sit amet</para>
```

**Note**: Fine grained traversal.

**Edit**: Compact code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::para/link" mode="copy"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="para/link"/>
    <xsl:template match="para/link" mode="copy">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()[preceding-sibling::node()[1]
                                    /self::link/parent::para]">
        <para>
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Should node `para` be copied instead of generated? What if it has attributes? <para lost="attribute">